# How to reuse the Entity Field in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I created an entity name is Student,

In that entity I created fields like Name , Age, Qualification etc.,
I wanted to add new field that is Contact number but I don't want to create new one.

Is there any chance to reuse the Mobile phone filed that is presented in Contact Entity..

If there how..??

Please help me..!!

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new one?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot move the mobile phone field from the Contact entity to the Student entity.

You will have to make a new field on the Student and hide the field on the Contact.

Or you could, add a lookup on your student to contact, so each student has a contact record associated and use the phone number that way.

Or you could, get rid of the student entity and just use the contact with the extra fields you needs, as a student is effectively a person which is effectively a contact.

The choice relies on your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You need to create a htm webresource and retrieve the contact number in the webresource, and then insert this htm webresource into the form. 
Please see this article for details:
http://www.gapconsulting.co.uk/DesktopModules/SunBlog/Handlers/Print.aspx?entryid=58